# On iOS15 prewarming issue on app launch using SceneDelegate

Tags: react-native, ios15, uiscenedelegate, carplay

We have a react-native project and we added "Scenes" via SceneDelegate (and changes on AppDelegate) in order to implement the CarPlay with "PointOfInterest" template.
We use react-native"0.63.3", Xcode"13.2.1".

When we launch the app after ~30min from the last launch, it skips the SplashScreen and everything are rendered wrong in terms of positioning. This was not an issue before iOS15.

We believe it's related with the new iOS15 feature of 'prewarming' and using ScenesDelegate because if we exclude the SceneDelegate the app launch is fine.

So is this an iOS bug or something in our 'Scenes' implementation.
We used this guide to add the CarPlay and Scenes in our app: https://adapptor.com.au/blog/enhance-existing-apps-with-carplay

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: We finally managed to solve it. Because of SceneDelegate and iOS15 prewarming, we had this issue and solved by transferring the RTCBridge protocol from 'didFinichWithLaunchOptions' on 'AppDelegate' to 'willConnectToSession' on 'SceneDelegate'